# WCF KnownTypes strange behavior

Tags: c#, wcf

We are trying to dynamically load a list of `KnownTypes` for our WCF Service, when loading the list of types this way (it doesn't work):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dll") || s.EndsWith(".exe"))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(d =>
  {
      try
      {
         Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(d);
         assembly.GetTypes().Where(f => f.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute), true))
        .Where(f => f.IsGenericType == false)
        .Where(f => f.FullName.StartsWith("AES."))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(t => copy.Add(t));
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          exceptions.Add(d, e);
       }
  });
```

We know the list of types is being generated via logging but get an obscure WCF endpoint error.

If we load the types this way it does work:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(f => f.GetTypes())
                             .Where(f => f.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute), true))
                             .Where(f => f.IsGenericType == false)
                             .Where(f => f.FullName.StartsWith("AES."))
                             .ToList()
                             .ForEach(t => copy.Add(t));
```

This way works no problem, the only difference is using the AppDomain manifest of assemblies to probe is different.

We get the same list regardless, the only difference (that we know) is that one way works and the other doesn't.

Any insight?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same directory?

Comment: There are a few asymmetries in the two code snippets you have shared.  In the first, you are loading assemblies into the current app domain from a file location; in the second, you are simply iterating over the assemblies currently loading into your current app domain.  Also, the first snippet iterates over two collections, rather than one.  Instead of ".ToList().Foreach(FilterCriteria and AssemblyLoad)", use ".Select(AssemblyLoad).Where(FilterCriteria).ToList().Foreach()".  Greater symmetry make it easier to debug.

Comment: possibly...  but the lists have the same types, same exact number...

Comment: It is also possible that you don't have directory access.  try putting a try/catch around the Directory.EnumerateFiles.

Comment: we do have access... like i said the  "returned" \lists are identical.

Comment: Are you consuming the collection in a separate app domain?

Comment: i don't think so, pretty certain that's a no.  besides, both ways are triggered the same way.